# SQL Join two tables? Select name category - CodeiGniter3

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I have a problem with the database.

I have 3 tables.
a) notebook
b) category_notes
c) domains

I have domain.id in the '**domains**' table.

In the '**notes**' table, I have **domain_id** and **notes_category_id**.
[image]

In the '**notes_category**' table, I have id, notes_category_name

[image]

Script action: Saves notes for a given domain.

Everything works correctly - the data is saved and read.

Now I would like to add a note type, I have already done this functionality - but I'm showing the ID of the note type and not its name.

Of course, I have a relationship that's dear.

Controller domains.php

```
public function notes($id)
    {
        $this->load->model('admin/notes_model');
        $result = $this->notes_model->get_by_domain_id($id);
        echo '{"records":' . json_encode( $result ) . '}';
    }
```

Model - domains_category_model.php

```
public function get($id = false)
{
    if ( $id == false) {

        $q = $this->db->get('notes_category');
        $q = $q->result();
    }
    else{

        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $q = $this->db->get('notes_category');
        $q = $q->row();     
    }
    return $q;
}
```

Controller - notes_category.php

```
public function get($id = false)
    {
        $result = $this->notes_category_model->get($id);
        echo '{"records":' . json_encode( $result ) . '}';
    }
```

Controller - notes.php

```
public function get($id = false)
    {
        $result = $this->notes_model->get($id);
        echo '{"records":' . json_encode( $result ) . '}';
    }
```

Model - Notes_model.php

```
public function get( $id = false)
    {
        if ( $id == false ) {
            $q = $this->db->get('notes');
            $q = $q->result();
        }
        else{
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $q = $this->db->get('notes');
            $q = $q->row();
        }
        return $q;
    }


    public function get_by_domain_id($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id_domain_rel', $id);
        $q = $this->db->get('notes');
        $q = $q->result();

        return $q;
    }
```

Comment: This is very hard to debug without the sql query. so you're saying if you request and ID of 1 the notes_category name is not linkowanie ?

Comment: @comphonia 
The data gets from the 'notebook' table, so it is known that there will be name_category_id - now I just do not know where to give some kind of join, which will connect these 2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive the name without conflict , use alias in select.

```
$this->db->select('n.* , n.id id_noted')->from('notes n')->get()->result();
$this->db->select('*, id id_noted')->from('notes')->get()->result();
```

I hope I understand what you want to do.